# Limiting number of inputs

Tags: reactjs

I´m trying to make a React calculator. It´s mostly done, but I have one problem I don´t know how to correct: I don´t want to let users enter expressions starting with more than one "0" AND expressions such as "01" should be replaced to just "1". I thought about using string methods to limit that, but it´s not budging.
EDIT: I know why my solution doesn´t work (input will never have more than one zero), but I don´t know any other way to fix it.

```
class Calculator extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
handleClick(evt) {
    const id = evt.target.id;
    const result = evt.target.value;
    if (id === "clear") {
    this.setState({ value: 0 });
    } else if (id === "equals") {
    this.setState({ value: math.eval(this.state.value) });
    } else {
    result.toString().includes("00");
    this.setState({ value: this.state.value + result.replace("00", "0") });
    console.log(this.state.value);
    }
}

render() {
    return (
    <div id="container">
        <Display value={this.state.value} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="zero" value={"0"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="one" value={"1"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="two" value={"2"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="three" value={"3"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="four" value={"4"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="five" value={"5"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="six" value={"6"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="seven" value={"7"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="eight" value={"8"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="nine" value={"9"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="decimal" value={"."} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="equals" value={"="} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="clear" value={"clear"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="add" value={"+"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="subtract" value={"-"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="multiply" value={"*"} />
        <Button onClick={this.handleClick} id="divide" value={"/"} />
    </div>
    );
}
}
export default Calculator;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few pointers...

- If you want `value` to be a string, make sure you don't change it to a number anywhere. You're doing this when id === 'clear'
- If you only want to test for `"00"` at the beginning of `value`, use `startsWith`, not `includes`.
- If you are using `setState` and the new state depends on the previous state, you must first access the state's previous value. The [rationale for this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is in the docs.

@daniel-hilgarth provides the correct way to use `setState` in this case.

Remove leading zero:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  value: `${prevState.value}${result}`.replace(/^0+\B/, "")
}));
```

There's all sorts of ways to do this. The regex above will identify leading zeros. For the case where you have only `"0"`, it doesn't match at all because `"0"` followed by a end of string (or boundary) doesn't match the regex which is `"0"` followed by "not a word boundary".

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I tried Daniel´s approach, but it disabled any input whatsoever.

Comment: The lambda body needs to have a return statement OR be wrapped in parens to tell JavaScript that the curly braces represents a JavaScript object and not a code body. Try ```this.setState(prevState => ({ value: `${prevState.value}${result}`.replace(/^00/, "0") }));```

Comment: That sort of works, but still allows "01" instead of "1". Didn´t think this would be so hard.

Comment: You just need to keep tweaking it. Such is the life of a programmer. I've updated my answer. Just keep refining it.

Comment: Thank you. Could a RegEx work? (Eg, detects 0 + Int and just replaces it with Int)

Comment: The solution is indeed using a regular expression and the `^0+` means "starts with one or more zeros." Of course, what you really wanted was "one or more zeros except when it's just zero by itself" which is why I added the `|| "0"` which means if you end up with an empty string, make it `0` instead.

Comment: I just need to see how to turn that into a "start with one more of zeros except when it´s just zero by itself AND drop the zero when it´s followed by a number". I tried doing ParseInt and adding exceptions for the operators but didn´t budge either.

Comment: What I mean is could I work out a RegEx which detects "01" and returns "1"? would that be possible?

Answer (score 2):

`result` will always contain just a single digit. What you want is to add the new digit to the existing value and only then replace:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ value: (prevState.value + result).replace("00", "0") }));
```

However, this code is buggy, because you would never be able to enter `100`, it would always be changed to `10`.

So the correct logic would be to add a start anchor:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ value: (prevState.value + result).replace(/^00/, "0") }));
```

**UPDATE:**

To achieve your actual goal, you can use something like the following (not the cleanest code, but should get my point across):

```
import React from "react";

const availableButtons = [
  "0",
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8",
  "9",
  ".",
  "=",
  "clear"
];
const operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"];

class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { values: [], value: "", currentNumber: "" };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(value) {
    if (value === "clear") {
      this.setState({ values: [], value: "", currentNumber: "" });
    } else if (value === "=") {
      this.setState({
        value: eval(this.state.value),
        values: [],
        currentNumber: ""
      });
    } else {
      if (operators.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          values: [...prevState.values, prevState.currentNumber, value],
          currentNumber: "",
          value: prevState.value + value
        }));
      } else {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          const currentNumber = this.formattedNumber(
            prevState.currentNumber,
            value
          );
          const newValue = prevState.values.join("") + currentNumber;
          return {
            currentNumber,
            value: newValue
          };
        });
      }
    }
  }

  formattedNumber(previousNumber, newSymbol) {
    if (!previousNumber && previousNumber !== 0) return newSymbol;
    if (
      previousNumber.length === 1 &&
      previousNumber === "0" &&
      newSymbol !== "."
    ) {
      return newSymbol;
    } else {
      return previousNumber + newSymbol;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="container">
        {this.state.value}
        <br />
        {availableButtons.concat(operators).map(x => (
          <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(x)} key={x}>
            {x}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Calculator;
```

[Working sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/n7956x196m)

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn´t work either! It simply disables any input of any number.

Comment: Thank you. It works, but it add one aditional problem: it still allows "01" and so on instead of replacing it to just "1". I tried to wrap it around Number, but that brings another problem which disables "+" and so on. I´m stuck here, didn´t think that would be so hard.

Comment: Well, you need to think about what you are trying to achieve here. You want to disallow leading zeroes in a string that can have an arbitrary amount of mathematical operators. The correct way would be to store this not as a plain string but as a series of objects, e.g. numbers and operators and then just format it into a string for display

Comment: You mean storing every result of every input before they change state?

Comment: 123+789/555 should be stored as something like `[{type: 'Number', value: '123'},{type:'operator', value: '+'},{type: 'Number', value: '789'},{type:'operator', value: '/'},{type: 'Number', value: '555'},]`

Comment: So you need to remember the current number while the user is entering numbers and then store it into the array when the user enters an operator

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, to be honest. Is that even possible in React, before updating state? I guess console.logging a lot.

Comment: No, the current number is just a state as well

Comment: Thank you. It does seem to work, but I wouldn´t be comfortable using it since it´s your code almost entirely (it feels unethical). I think I´m going to stick with the RegEx (seeing if I can add a "replace it with a number if it´s 0 + number" and work out a solution when it´s two decimal points together)

Comment: It's fine, you can use it. However, try to understand what it is doing, you will learn something along the way. And in learning what it does you can adopt it to your own style and make it your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line

```
this.setState({ value: this.state.value + result.replace("00", "0") });
```

to this

```
let num = this.state.value + Number(result);
this.setState({ value: Number(num).toString()});
```

I guess that will solve.

Comment: 1. It doesn't solve the problem and 2. Never access the previous state in `setState` like this. Always use the overload with the callback: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/react-docs-now-recommends-using-function-with-prevstate-inside-of-setstate

Comment: What Daniel said.

Comment: Thank you, but that only brings more problems, since you now can´t press any input that isn´t a number (such as "+" and so on)